# More jobs for company X doesn't work, shows all jobs?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

There is a link on a company page that says:

**More jobs at company X**

I would of thought this would filter the jobs for that specific company, but it doesn't.  Here's the screen shots:

[image]

When I click this link I am presented with over 2k jobs at QuickenLoans but when I click any of these jobs they are for completely different companies.  Filter doesn't appear to work.  I'm not even sure if the number 2k is valid, I can't imagine quicken loans is hiring 2k developers!

Comment: Yeah, there's something weird going on there.

Comment: @JasonPunyon I think you just need to apply the filter, instead of this http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/Telerik you need to redirect to this  
http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=Telerik and you should be good to go.

Comment: @JonH A little more complicated, sadly :/ /employer/{name} is a special route to only show jobs _posted by that employer_, going to ?searchTerm={name} would also show results of other job listings that have that company's name in it.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi simple fix redirect here: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/company name#jobs like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/sparo-labs#jobs this takes you exactly to where you need to be, open jobs by that company.  in the case of my post for quicken loans it could be http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/quicken-loans#jobs

Comment: @JonH yeah, but we'd still have to fix the link for companies that don't have an associated company page. :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks - a fix is going out now!

Comment: This still doesn't work...again.

Comment: Steps to reproduce go to this: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/99085/software-engineer-lightbeam-health-solutions scroll to the bottom all the way.  Click the link that says see all lightbeam health solutions jobs.  By clicking it, the query returns 52 jobs but shows jobs for companies like Quicken, Pinacle, etc.

Comment: @JonH thanks for sticking in there with this one. Originally I diagnosed this as a bug affecting one side of an A/B test we are currently running. Now I realize the issue is probably more general. Our data model around Jobs and Employers is rather loose by design, in order to serve some specific needs of some of our employer users. One drawback of the looseness is that we don't currently have a rock solid way of returning a list of jobs by company _aside from a text search against company name_. The longer the company name, and the more generic the words in it, the less ideal the results.